# Объясните пожалуйста что такое optional в discord.py (или вообще в python) и как решить проблему

Tags: python-3.x, бот, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Я хочу создать текстовый канал командой в определённой категории. Я всё сделал, но не могу добавить именно в категорию. Я поискал в интернете, ничего не нашёл (я новичок). У меня есть id категории но если я просто вставляю его:

```py
await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name=name, overwrites=overwrites, category = 774723755490410516)
```

то пишет что не тот тип:

```py
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'
```

В документации написано что надо тип `Optional`, но я совсем не знаю что это такое.
Документация: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel

[image: скрин документации]

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`typing.Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) обозначает что указанный аргумент может быть как указанного типа (в данном случае `CategoryChannel`), так и `None`.

Для получения категории, как и любого другого канала по ID можно использовать [`Guild.get_channel(ID)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel).

```py
await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name, category=ctx.guild.get_channel(850289294063283387)) 
# name - "позиционный" аргумент, его не обязательно указывать по имени ("var" вместо "name = var")
```

Либо вы можете использовать метод `create_text_channel` самого объекта категории: [`CategoryChannel.create_text_channel`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel.create_text_channel)

```py
category = ctx.guild.get_channel(850289294063283387)
await category.create_text_channel(name)
```